# How to change the contents of a file included in an *.msi with VBScript

Tags: vbscript, windows-installer, setup-project, orca

Given an installer generated with a VS2010 Setup Project, I would like to swap out a .NET DLL with another one without changing the name.

I am already altering the `msi` file according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253796/how-to-modify-contents-replace-a-binary-of-an-msi-file-as-a-post-build-step), swapping out the contents of an entry in the "Binary" table.

I have located the file in question using Orca. It resides in the only cabinet file. I have located this cabinet file in the "Media" table. I'm not sure how to change this cabinet file (API) and I suspect I'd have to change some information in the MSI database too (the "ProcessorArchitecture" record for the assembly in the "MsiAssemblyName" table).

**Rationale:** I'm making an installer for a Autodesk Revit 2011 plugin. These are registered using an assembly `RevitAddinUtility.dll` which must be bundled with the installer. This assembly comes in two flavors, one for 32-bit and one for 64-bit installations. I need to swap in the correct version when creating the installer, to avoid writing more than one installers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a workaround I'm using in the meantime:

- add both files, one named `RevitAddinUtility.dll` the other `RevitAddinUtility64.dll`
- in the PostBuild-Event, ask the user if the setup project should be for 64bit.
- if yes, then change the names of the files:

  ```
  If 6 = MsgBox("Build for 64bit?", 4, "Setup PostBuild event for DesignPerformanceViewer") Then
      Dim installer : Set installer = Wscript.CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
      Dim database : Set database = installer.OpenDatabase(PATH_TO_MSI, msiOpenDatabaseModeTransact)
      Dim sqlQuery : sqlQuery = "SELECT `FileName`, `Component_` FROM File"
      Dim view : Set view = database.OpenView(sqlQuery)
      view.Execute
      Dim record : Set record = view.Fetch
      While Not record Is Nothing        
          If InStr(record.StringData(1), "RevitAddInUtility.dll") Then  
              record.StringData(1) = "REVITA~2.DLL|RevitAddInUtility32.dll"
              view.Modify msiViewModifyUpdate, record    
          ElseIf InStr(record.StringData(1), "RevitAddInUtility64.dll") Then    
              record.StringData(1) = "REVITA~1.DLL|RevitAddInUtility.dll"
              view.Modify msiViewModifyUpdate, record    
          End If    
          Set record = view.Fetch
      Wend
      database.Commit   
  End If
  ```

Comment: Sorry, you just broke the install in several ways.  For one you changed the name of the assembly without changing the actual contents ( which will break a .NET assembly ) and you also created a component rule violation by changing the keypath with out changing the ComponentID.

Comment: actually, I changed the name of the assembly *before* adding it to the install and then *changed it back* to the real name afterwards. Could you provide a pointer on "keypath"? I admit to poking around in the dark with a way to short stick here...